# How can I prevent a certificate from being trusted?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, certificate, ssl-certificate

There exist two certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs` that I'd like to permanently remove. However, just deleting the pem files doesn't do it - those are regenerated when `ca-certificates` is updated. How could I go about permanently marking a certificate as "untrusted"?

Comment: See related on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/440594/42822)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Linux Mint 17.1, the `/etc/ssl/certs` directory contains one actual file (`ca-certificates.crt`) and about 500 links to files in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/` . If you went to the target directory and deleted the unwanted files there, you might have slightly more permanent deletion.

But, the `ca-certificates` package looks like it would just re-create all the files again when it's updated, so you could either stop updating that package, or delete the unwanted files each time after it updates.

Or best looking, the answer linked in the comment above looks like it should work to "de-select" some certificates by running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure` did exactly what I was after. Accepting!